# How to execute a command in bash language and check its result

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to learn the bash language. How do I execute a Linux command with a dynamic argument and check whether or not the returning string is empty. For example:

```
if ls "my_directory123" == `emtpy string` then
    ....
end
```

Comment: You can use `if [ "$my_directory23" = "" ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the result of the command to a variable and compare it as a string.

```
result=$(ls "my_directory123")
if [ "$result" = "" ]
then
  echo empty
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing for an empty directory pass in the first positional parameter `"$1"`, you can test:

```
if test -z "$(ls -A "$1")" ; then
```

or

```
if [ -z "$(ls -A "$1")" ]; then
```

which are equivalent uses of the `test` of `[` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
TEST=`ls`
if [$TEST == ""]; then
echo "do something"
fi
```

if you want to run this in the terminal you key in each line at a time. If you prefer you can put everything in a file prepend with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to make an executable string once you run

```
chmod +x FILENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to call Command Substitution and check for returned value. Some think like this

```
  x=$(ls path)    
  if [ -z "$x" ] ;then echo empty ; else echo no empty; fi
```